# How to use unsigned ints in Assembly

Tags: int, unsigned

I'm writing a small program in assembly and i need to calculate an int that is a power of two and uses the last bit in a register. Let's say i need to calculate 2^31  and store the result in ebx register.

How can I treat this int as unsigned for arithmetic operations?

Answer (score 2):

To compute a power of two you use a shift left operation - something like

```
SAL    EAX,31
```

Addition and subtraction operations are the same for signed and unsigned values - i.e. it is only when you do something with the result (like displaying it) that you have to consider it signed or unsigned

For division and multiplication there are different instructions for signed (`IDIV`, `IMUL`) and unsigned (`DIV`, `MUL`)

Comment: That's what I use. But as you said, when I display it I get a negative number. How can I display it correctly?

Comment: How are you converting the number into a string for display? That is the place that needs changes..

Comment: I call `printf` with a formatted string and the number as arguments

Answer (score 1):

Data in many assembly languages (i.e instruction set architectures) is typeless, except to the extent that it has a size: i.e. 8 bits is a "type" different from 16.

Your EBX register is neither signed nor unsigned; it's just a bank of 32 bits.

The semantics of the bits (what the bits mean) depends on the operation being applied, not on any kind of declared type like in a higher level language.

x86 distinguishes "logical shifts" from "arithmetic shifts".

So to calculate `1 << 31` you want to use a logical shift left (SAL). For shifting signed quantities use the arithmetic shifts.

Comment: In some instruction set architectures, there are different instructions for signed and unsigned addition, even though the machine is two's complement. MIPS is this way; it has `add` and `addu` instructions. Ironically, though, GCC uses `addu` for signed numbers also. The plain `add` generates an overflow trap, but `addu` implements wrapping arithmetic. C programs, though, often expect wrapping arithmetic from signed numbers also, rather than an oveflow trap!